# Repetitive Info appearing using Blade HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, caching, laravel-blade

Below is my code, I want to understand how to fix the problem of my main functions section include the management, cashier and report appearing twice on the web page. I also added some javascript code at the bottom trying to call the ID from the 'you're logged in' message and have it disappear after three seconds. When I added this code, it is just making the duplicate section disappear after three seconds and not the message.

I tried adding this block -  loggedInMessage.style.display = 'block'; - to the js code, below the start of the if statement, but that is just making the whole web page disappear after three seconds.

```html
<x-app-layout>
  <x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 leading-tight">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-utensils"></i> {{ __('Restaurant Manager') }}
    </h2>
  </x-slot>

  <div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg" id="loggedInMessage">
        <div class="p-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
          {{ __("You're logged in!") }}
        </div>

        <div class="center-container">
          <div class="center-content">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">Main Functions</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4 management">
              <a href="/management">
                <h4>
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-database"></i> Management
                </h4>
                <img width="50px" src="{{asset('images/management.svg')}}" />
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 cashier">
              <a href="/cashier">
                <h4>
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-money-bill-transfer"></i> Cashier
                </h4>
                <img width="50px" src="{{asset('images/cashier.svg')}}" />
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 report">
              <a href="/report">
                <h4>
                  <i class="fas fa-list-check"></i> Report
                </h4>
                <img width="50px" src="{{asset('report/management.svg')}}" />
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const loggedInMessage = document.getElementById('loggedInMessage');

      const hideLoggedInMessage = () => {
        if (loggedInMessage) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            loggedInMessage.style.display = 'none';
          }, 3000);
        }
      };

      hideLoggedInMessage();
    });
  </script>
</x-app-layout>
```

Comment: Your loggedInMessage container holds rest of the page too. You may want to move the ID to the next div `<div class="p-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100" id="loggedInMessage">
        <div class="p-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
          {{ __("You're logged in!") }}
        </div>`

Comment: And do you have some includes that you are not showing, that perhaps is including this file too?